# How to add the UDID to the testFlight Portal

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

Hi one of our team members wants to add their device to the testFlight account, I have sent the Invitation from the portal and they have accepted It, and I need UDID of that device for the provision profile, **they should send it manually?or TestFlight Portal will fetch their UDID If they just accept the invitation ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once people(Tester) accepts the invitation they get a mail from testflight with subject **Get Started.** If invitees click on the get started and completes all the required step successfully you will get a auto generated email from Testflight
with subject line **XYZ added a device** and the body of the mail contains the following details.

[image]

Then you can add this device id in provisioning profile manually. The only thing is "invitees must use his/her mobile device for opening all the mail from testflight".

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need to add the UDID to the provisioning profile.

Then sign in to Testflightapp.com and follow below path:

Apps->App name->builds->click on latest build

You will see all the UDID's in the provisioning profile from there you can select the newly added UDID.

[image: Image for your reference]

Comment: Thanx for your Reply,,Will testFlight web portal will help to get the Device UDID or we should ask that member to send his Device UDID manually?

Answer (score 0):

You need update the provisioning profile with new UDID. If the build is already uploaded then go to settings->Permissions and update the new Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Thanx for your reply,,Yea I know i need to update the Profile with new UDID, my Question is They should send the UDID manually or testFlight web portal will gather the UDID from the device if they login from their device?

Comment: Ok, If you already updated the UDID in profile, just need to update the permissions make sure the UDID is selected. Then should be able to access app.

Comment: Test Flight will automatically detect it.

Comment: But i cant see the newly addded UDID in testFlight

Comment: Then -  1.Check if your profile has new UDID's(U can open it in textedit and search) if its there then Update the profile using "Update Profile »" Option

Answer (score 0):

When your friends the invitation via their devices, TestFlight will have their devices info (you can check People menu on TestFlight). Then you have to register their devices (UDID) for your provisioning profile and update the profile on TestFlight

Comment: But there are no any newly added UDID in the people Menu

Comment: @RaviKiran you may want to check out this http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829918-i-invited-a-team-member-and-they-accepted-the-invite-but-don-t-show-up-in-the-people-section

Comment: yea his emailId is showing up correctly.But its not showing his UDID...  Should i tell him to send his device UDID separately??

Comment: @RaviKiran can you paste the screenshot of your testflight page here. 'Advice' with every  person name, there is number written(no. of devices that person have) & a info button right of it. click on the info button you will get the person device UDID.

Answer (score 0):

If the user accepts the invitation and tries adding the device to testflight without it being on the provisioning profile the user will not be able to use that device to play with your app. You need to get the UDID and add it to the provisioning profile at https://developer.apple.com download that new provisioning profile and upload your app again with this new provisioning profile. **The Device's UDID MUST be in the provisioning profile for it to be able to download the app**

Testflight no longer sends the UDID as Apple removed `uniqueIdentifier` completely in `iOS 7` and deprecated it in `iOS 6.1` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

The option to be able to send the `UDID` was removed from version `1.0 BETA 1 - 30 March 2012`

> UDID is no longer collected by the SDK. During testing please use [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]]; to send the UDID so you can identify your testers. For release do not set +setDeviceIdentifier. See Beta Testing and Release Differentiation in the README or online at https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.0beta1/

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask user to send his UDID and his Apple id.(User can find his UDID by connecting the device to mac,then go to iTunes -> click on device icon -> click on serial number. For Apple id go to Settings -> iTunes & App store)
2. Add the UDID in developer account(under device section).
3. Create provisioning profile.
4. Now login to itunesconnect.apple.com,go to Users and Roles, add the user using user's Apple id(user's Apple id you got in step 1).
5. Once you add the user, test flight will send the invitation mail to the user on given Apple id(generally it's a mail id user used to sign in to itunes). Ask user the to accept the invitation which he got on Apple id(mail id).
6. Once user accept the invitation, upload your build to TestFlight using Xcode.
7. Now go to iTunes-> My apps -> Select your app  -> TestFlight -> Internal Testing -> Add internal tester(user you added in step 5) -> select version to test(select the build you have just uploaded from Xcode).
8. Once you click on start testing, user will get the Testflight notification on their device to download the app.

Note: In order to upload the build to iTunes, you should create your app in iTunes under My Apps section -> +.